# Question about the dimension of the intersection of two subspaces of a vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $M, N$ be two subspaces of a vector space $V$ with dimension $k$. Suppose that $\dim M=m$, $\dim N =n$. It is said that $\dim M \cap N \geq m+n-k$. Suppose that $M, N$ are two parallel planes in $V=R^3$. Then $n=3$, $m=n=2$. By the formula, we have $\dim M \cap N \geq 1$. But $M, N$ do not intersect. Do we think that $M, N$ intersect at infinity and the intersection of $M, N$ is a line? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should try to prove that $\dim(M+N)=\dim M+\dim N-\dim (M\cap N)$. That's inclusion-exclusion for vector spaces. Take a basis of $M\cap N$. Complete it into a basis of $M$ on one hand. And into a basis of $N$ on the other hand. Altogehter, this gives a basis of $M+N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the properties of a subspace? Is it possible for a plane to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if it doesn't pass through the origin?